# How to change gl_PointSize in the vertex shader?

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

I'm optimizing my particle renderer to work with `GL_POINTS` and now I need to adjust the size of the points using `gl_PointSize` in the vertex shader to scale the particles the right amount from the vertex shader.
This is the vertex shader I have now:

```c
#version 330 core

layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;
layout (location = 1) in uint uv;

uniform mat4 projection;
uniform mat4 view;

void main(){
    gl_PointSize = 10; // No difference with gl_PointSize = 1000
    gl_Position = projection * view * vec4(position, 1.0);
}
```

Changing the `gl_PointSize` doesn't seem to make a difference when changed in the vertex shader.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to enable `GL_PROGRAM_POINT_SIZE` (see [`glEnable`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glEnable.xhtml) and [`gl_PointSize`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/gl_PointSize.xhtml)):

```cpp
glEnable(GL_PROGRAM_POINT_SIZE);
```

Answer (score 2):

[OpenGL Reference - gl_PointSize](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/gl_PointSize.xhtml)

> **Description**:
>
> In the vertex, tessellation evaluation and geometry languages, a single global instance of the gl_PerVertex named block is available and its gl_PointSize member is an output that receives the intended size of the point to be rasterized, in pixels. It may be written at any time during shader execution. If GL_PROGRAM_POINT_SIZE is enabled, gl_PointSize is used to determine the size of rasterized points, otherwise it is ignored by the rasterization stage.